# cannot connecting Microsoft Flows with HTTP request using certificate authentification

Tags: http, powerapps, power-automate

I am a new user for Microsoft Flows.

I have a requirement for Connecting the Microsoft Flow with HTTP Request.

When connecting the HTTP Request, I am using the Client Certificate with the .pfx certificate file.

I am using the below format :

{ "type": "ClientCertificate", "pfx": "aGVsbG8g...d29ybGQ=", "password": "myPassword" }

I am adding the pfx file in Base64 Encoding Format and Password in Plain Text format.

While running the Flow, I get the below error :

BadRequest. Unable to load the certificate private key. Please check that the password of the authentication certificate is correct, then try again.

Thanks, :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar experience, but the solution here is simple: The error message is right, either you have the wrong or incomplete base64 certificate string (copy-paste errors happen) or you have the wrong password to the certificate. There really is nothing more to it, the JSON form looks fine.